# How do I compare the first elements of multiple lists and append to a new list if they are equal?

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing, compare, element

I have a list of data that looks like this shortened piece of data right here.

```
[[743, 5043.0, 'N/A', 19.40393776, 7.18, 15.487], [744, 6117.0, 'N/A', 19.22138894, 49.29, 15.341], [745, 5152.0, 'N/A', 16.46983774, 7.94, 15.788], [746, 4856.0, 1.5936507936507938, 9.27358173, 2.47, 15.302], [747, 4537.0, 1.0317880794701988, 6.02930329, 2.85, 15.784], [748, 4989.0, 'N/A', 2.696370652, 1.58, 15.269], [749, 5185.0, 0.8675585284280938, 5.349553819, 2.55, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 3.94105221, 1.7, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 8.10904807, 1.3, 15.416]]
```

Right now I have a list of lists, and the first element represents the Kepler Object of Interest number. I sorted my data to display the lists in order of their first element. My goal is to create a list of lists of lists where all lists with matching first elements are placed in a list together. For example, there are three lists with `749` that should be placed in one list together. I'm struggling to create a program that iterates through all my lists and compares the first element to an unknown amount of other first elements. What is the easiest way to do this?

**Goal:**

```
[[[743, 5043.0, 'N/A', 19.40393776, 7.18, 15.487]], [[744, 6117.0, 'N/A', 19.22138894, 49.29, 15.341]], [[745, 5152.0, 'N/A', 16.46983774, 7.94, 15.788]], [[746, 4856.0, 1.5936507936507938, 9.27358173, 2.47, 15.302]], [[747, 4537.0, 1.0317880794701988, 6.02930329, 2.85, 15.784]], [[748, 4989.0, 'N/A', 2.696370652, 1.58, 15.269]], [[749, 5185.0, 0.8675585284280938, 5.349553819, 2.55, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 3.94105221, 1.7, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 8.10904807, 1.3, 15.416]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using converting the list of lists into a pandas DataFrame is a good way to go:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([[743, 5043.0, 'N/A', 19.40393776, 7.18, 15.487], [744, 6117.0, 'N/A', 19.22138894, 49.29, 15.341], [745, 5152.0, 'N/A', 16.46983774, 7.94, 15.788], [746, 4856.0, 1.5936507936507938, 9.27358173, 2.47, 15.302], [747, 4537.0, 1.0317880794701988, 6.02930329, 2.85, 15.784], [748, 4989.0, 'N/A', 2.696370652, 1.58, 15.269], [749, 5185.0, 0.8675585284280938, 5.349553819, 2.55, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 3.94105221, 1.7, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 8.10904807, 1.3, 15.416]])
y = x.groupby(0).apply(lambda z: list(z.values))
Goal = [[list(z) for z in y[idx]] for idx in y.index]
```

I believe this is formatted, and grouped, the way you describe.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in features in Python you can use dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [[743, 5043.0, 'N/A', 19.40393776, 7.18, 15.487], [744, 6117.0, 'N/A', 19.22138894, 49.29, 15.341], [745, 5152.0, 'N/A', 16.46983774, 7.94, 15.788], [746, 4856.0, 1.5936507936507938, 9.27358173, 2.47, 15.302], [747, 4537.0, 1.0317880794701988, 6.02930329, 2.85, 15.784], [748, 4989.0, 'N/A', 2.696370652, 1.58, 15.269], [749, 5185.0, 0.8675585284280938, 5.349553819, 2.55, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 3.94105221, 1.7, 15.416], [749, 5185.0, 'N/A', 8.10904807, 1.3, 15.416]]
d = OrderedDict()
for inner in l:
    if inner[0] in d:
        d[inner[0]].append(inner)
    else:
        d[inner[0]] = [inner]

list(d.values())
```

I used OrderedDict so it preserve order of original items.